# How do I call opendir without using malloc'd memory?

Tags: c, malloc

Just for educational purposes, I'm writing a C program without any malloc, and I'm checking that there's no heap usage by using [mallinfo().uordblks](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html). I've noticed that the function [opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) triggers a huge spike in malloc'd memory according to mallinfo, and I'm not sure why. I'm wondering if there's a way to give opendir a stack-allocated buffer in order to do what it needs so that I can avoid this (similar to `setvbuf`, which I used to avoid buffering on the heap for stdout/stderr). Bascially, **how do I read the contents of a directory without using heap-allocated memory?**. If it makes a difference, I'm on a Linux machine.

Comment: `opendir` is returning a pointer to some new object. How do you expect it to create this object without dynamic allocation?

Comment: roll your own? `opendir` uses `malloc`, in glibc anyway: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/opendir.c.html

Comment: @EugeneSh. By providing it a stack-allocated chunk of memory similar to how it's done with `setvbuf`.

Comment: You will probably have to roll your own version of opendir/readdir/closedir by using the open/read/close system calls.

Comment: Speaking of system calls, here's an even stranger challenge for you (when you finish this one): write a program without using the library (`-nostdlib`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, any more than you could use stdio without the possibility that it calls `malloc`, or likewise many other components in libc. Fundamentally there's no reason that any of the standard library functions can't use `malloc` internally, although for many it would have to be conditional with fallback paths (because they're not allowed to fail, or because they need to be async-signal-safe, etc.) and for lots it would make no sense whatsoever for them to do so in a reasonable implementation.

In any case, since unlike with stdio (where you can do low-level fd operations instead) there is no portable directory-access API that's not normally implemented with a userspace buffer object (`DIR`), you either have to accept that it uses `malloc` or go with a non-portable lower-level interface (on Linux, the `SYS_getdents64` syscall).

One option on systems that let you define your own `malloc` would be doing that, and having it allocate from a fixed pool or direct `mmap` or similar, if there's a reason you need to avoid whatever `malloc` normally does on your system.